# C++: Getting T** from vector<vector<T>>

Tags: c++, stl

I'm interfacing with a C library that needs a 2D array of type `float**`, whose size is determined at runtime. I'd like to use an STL container such as std::vector to manage this memory, but `vector<vector<float>>::data()` gives `vector<float>*`, not `float**`. What can I do?

Comment: Allocate your own `float**` or `vector<float*>` and populate it with pointers to inner vectors' `data()`. You can't get a `float**` for free - it just doesn't exist in your chosen data structure.

Comment: May I ask why my question was downvoted? I tried quite hard to ask the question concisely, and searched extensively before posting. How could I have made it better? The accepted answer is interesting and insightful. Not seeing why this post was badly received...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new *vector* holding the pointers to all the internal arrays managed by the inner *vector* of your *vector of vectors*:

```
void old_c_function(float** floats, std::size_t X, std::size_t Y)
{
    for(auto x = 0U; x < X; ++x)
        for(auto y = 0U; y < Y; ++y)
            std::cout << "[" << x << ", " << y << "] = " << floats[x][y] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> v =
    {
        {1.2, 3.4, 5.6},
        {7.8, 9.0, 1.2},
    };

    // create a new vector to hold the pointers to the arrays
    // managed by the internal vectors
    std::vector<float*> v_ptrs;
    v_ptrs.reserve(v.size());

    // add the addresses of all the arrays to the new vector
    std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        [&v_ptrs](auto& v){ v_ptrs.push_back(v.data()); });

    // call your legacy function using your pointer vector
    old_c_function(v_ptrs.data(), v.size(), v.front().size());
}
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0] = 1.2
[0, 1] = 3.4
[0, 2] = 5.6
[1, 0] = 7.8
[1, 1] = 9
[1, 2] = 1.2
```

**NOTE:**

Obviously if you change your vector you will need to rebuild your pointer vector because the addresses may well change.

You can either rebuild it on the fly through some wrapper function like so:

```
void new_wrapper_function(std::vector<std::vector<float>>& v)
{
    // create a new vector to hold the pointers to the arrays
    // managed by the internal vectors
    std::vector<float*> v_ptrs;
    v_ptrs.reserve(v.size());

    // add the addresses of all the arrays to the new vector
    std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v)
        [&v_ptrs](auto& v){ v_ptrs.push_back(v.data()); });

    // call your legacy function using your pointer vector
    old_c_function(v_ptrs.data(), v.size(), v.front().size());
}
```

Or else (my favorite) build a wrapper `class` to encapsulate both vectors and update the pointer vector whenever the primary vector increases in capacity in one of its dimensions.

Comment: ... and then you hope that the C function just has a sloppy declaration and actually treats its argument as a `float* const*`.

Comment: @aschepler The C function can update the arrays without a problem, the pointers point to the actual data in the original array.

Comment: How about a `std::copy` to `std::back_inserter(v)`?

Comment: @aschepler Because I am not copying the `float` values, I am taking the addresses of the first element of each internal array.

Comment: Oh, duh. A `std::vector<float>` wouldn't initialize a `float*` very well. Nope.

Comment: You will need to re-run all this code if the vector is ever resized (or recapacitated)

Answer (score 0):

I would say use

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> shape;
std::pair<float **, shape> obj;
```

or

```
std::tuple<float **, int, int> obj;
```

whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do?

a) Use a 1d vector

```
 typedef std::vector<float> FloatVec_t
```

b) To access the 1D vector, you can compute the 1d index from the 2d coordinates, a trivial function that can be optimized away.

```
 // size_t maxCol; is runtime size info

 size_t indx1D(size_t r, size_t c) 
 { return static_cast<size_t>((r*maxCol) + c); }
```

c) create/use getElement(x,y) for 2d access:

```
 FloatVec_t  fltVec1D;  

 // 2d access
 float* getElement(size_t r, size_t c) { return (fltVec [indx1D (r,c)]); }
```

d) create arr on top of the 1D vector.  See working code below.

Environment:

Ubuntu 15.10;  g++ version 5.2.1 20151028; older Dell Athlon

Code / MCVE:

```
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_chrono.hh"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

typedef std::vector<float> FloatVec_t;

class T537_t
{
private:
   FloatVec_t fltVec1D;
   size_t     maxCol;
   size_t     maxRow;

public:
   T537_t () = default;
   ~T537_t() = default;

   int exec(size_t a_MaxCol,
            size_t a_MaxRow)
      {
         maxCol = a_MaxCol;
         maxRow = a_MaxRow;

         size_t N = maxCol * maxRow;

         std::cout << "\n  sizeof(float): " << sizeof(float) << std::endl;

         std::cout << "\n  Col x Row: " << maxCol << " x " << maxRow
                   << " = " << N

                   << "\n\n  reserved " << N << " elements in 1D vec" << std::endl;

         fltVec1D.reserve(N);

         std::cout << "\n  initialize 1D vec with values computed from row and col" << std::flush;

         for (uint r=1; r<=maxRow; ++r)
            for (uint c=1; c<=maxCol; ++c)
               fltVec1D.push_back (100.1F * static_cast<float> (((r-1)*maxCol) + c));

         std::cout << "\n\n  report fltVec1D addrs: " << std::flush;
         for (uint r=0; r<maxRow; ++r)
         {
            std::cout << "\n    fltVec1D[" << std::setw(2) << r << "]  " << std::flush;
            for (uint c=0; c<maxCol; ++c)
               std::cout << "  " << std::setw(8)
                         << &fltVec1D[indx1D(r,c)] << std::flush;
            std::cout << std::flush;
         }

         std::cout << "\n\n  report fltVec1D data: " << std::flush;
         for (uint r=0; r<maxRow; ++r)
         {
            std::cout << "\n    fltVec1D[" << std::setw(2) << r << "]  " << std::flush;
            for (uint c=0; c<maxCol; ++c)
               std::cout << "  " << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(5)
                         << fltVec1D[indx1D(r,c)] << std::flush;
            std::cout << std::flush;
         }

         // overlay arr on top of fltVec1D data
         float** arr   = new float* [maxRow]; // arr contains rows
         {
            for (size_t r=0; r < maxRow; ++r)
               arr[r] = getElement(r,0);      // rows already exist
         }                                    // and start at col 0,


         std::cout << "\n\n  report arr data: " << std::flush;
         for (size_t r=0; r<maxRow; ++r)
         {
            std::cout << "\n         arr[" << std::setw(2) << r << "]  " << std::flush;
            for (size_t c=0; c<maxCol; ++c)
            {
               std::cout << "  " << std::setw(8) << std::setprecision(5)
                         << arr[r][c] << std::flush;
            }
            std::cout << std::flush;
         }

         std::cout << "\n\n\n  report address diffs:   &arr[r][c] - getElement(r,c) : \n" << std::flush;
         for (uint r=0; r<maxRow; ++r)
         {
            std::cout << "\n          row" << std::setw(2) << r << "   " << std::flush;
            for (uint c=0; c<maxCol; ++c)
            {
               float* addr1 = & arr[r][c];
               float* addr2 = getElement(r,c);
               std::cout << "  " << std::setw(8) << (addr1 - addr2) << std::flush;
            }
            std::cout << std::flush;
         }

         delete[] arr; // delete of  float** arr   = new float* [maxCol];

         return 0;
      }

private: // methods

   size_t indx1D(size_t r, size_t c)
      {
         assert(r<maxRow);
         assert(c<maxCol);
         return static_cast<size_t>((r*maxCol) + c);
      }

   float* getElement(size_t r, size_t c) { return (& fltVec1D [indx1D(r,c) ] ); }

}; // class T537_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if(argc > 1)
   {
      std::cout << "\nargc: " << argc << std::endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1) std::cout << argv[i] << " ";
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   if(3 != argc) {
      std::cerr << "\n  2 Required parameters: maxCol maxRow " << std::endl;
      return (0);
   }

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T537_t   t537;

      Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

      retVal = t537.exec(static_cast<size_t>(std::atoi(argv[1])),   // col - i.e. 5
                         static_cast<size_t>(std::atoi(argv[2])));  // row - i.e. 20

      auto  duration_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

      std::cout << "\n\n  t537.exec() duration  " << duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
   }

   return(retVal);
}
```

Output example for command line parameters 3 5

```
  sizeof(float): 4

  Col x Row: 3 x 5 = 15

  reserved 15 elements in 1D vec

  initialize 1D vec with values computed from row and col

  report fltVec1D addrs: 
    fltVec1D[ 0]    0x179dc50  0x179dc54  0x179dc58
    fltVec1D[ 1]    0x179dc5c  0x179dc60  0x179dc64
    fltVec1D[ 2]    0x179dc68  0x179dc6c  0x179dc70
    fltVec1D[ 3]    0x179dc74  0x179dc78  0x179dc7c
    fltVec1D[ 4]    0x179dc80  0x179dc84  0x179dc88

  report fltVec1D data: 
    fltVec1D[ 0]       100.1     200.2     300.3
    fltVec1D[ 1]       400.4     500.5     600.6
    fltVec1D[ 2]       700.7     800.8     900.9
    fltVec1D[ 3]        1001    1101.1    1201.2
    fltVec1D[ 4]      1301.3    1401.4    1501.5

  report arr data: 
         arr[ 0]       100.1     200.2     300.3
         arr[ 1]       400.4     500.5     600.6
         arr[ 2]       700.7     800.8     900.9
         arr[ 3]        1001    1101.1    1201.2
         arr[ 4]      1301.3    1401.4    1501.5


  report address diffs:   &arr[r][c] - getElement(r,c) : 

          row 0            0         0         0
          row 1            0         0         0
          row 2            0         0         0
          row 3            0         0         0
          row 4            0         0         0
```

Summary:

This unit test code demonstrates:

a) build and initializes a 1d std::vector.

b) creates "float** arr" using the the built-in-array construct and new.

c) A quick for-loop loads each row pointer using getElement(r,0).

d) The unit test displays the same info (addresses and data) from both the 1d vec (fltVec1D) and arr

e) The test ends by comparing the addresses which demo that the two names provide access to the same addresses and thus the same data.

"arr" is appropriate for delivering to the legacy function (not tested).

Comment: How does this help pass something to an existing function that requires a `float**`?

Comment: Usually when function documentation claims a `float** p` represents an mxn 2D array, it means that the elements are `p[i][j]` where `i<m && j<n`, not `*p[i*n+j]`.  (Yeah, so there's no array of arrays involved there. Nevertheless.)

Comment: @aschepler - thanks for the question and comment .. I decided to provide some code, and had to look for it, then modify it.